# NullPointerException while I'm trying to unit test Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

When I try to test my CRUD operations in my Spring Boot Applications, I get NullPointerException saying that `this.Repository` is null. What can I do to resolve this issue? Am I missing something?

My test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class AppointmentServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Test
    void shouldGetAllAppointments() {
        List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
        appointments.add(new Appointment());

        given(appointmentRepository.findAll()).willReturn(appointments);

        List<Appointment> expectedAppointments = appointmentService.getAllAppointments();

        assertEquals(expectedAppointments, appointments);
        verify(appointmentRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.hospitalmanagementsystem.repository.AppointmentRepository.findAll()" because "this.appointmentRepository" is null
```

Comment: what are `given` and `verify` methods? To which library do they belong? Probably makes sense to add a corresponding tag

Comment: Hello, `given` is from `org.mockito.BDDMockito` and `verify` is from `org.mockito.Mockito` . Maybe the issue is caused by wrong static imports?

Comment: I haven't worked with BDDMockito. You can try `Mockito.when(appointmentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(appointments);` Also, Are you sure you're running with JUnit 4 I mean is it your real intention? Or you need JUnit 5 really?

Comment: Hey, you are right. I was trying to run with JUnit4 while I needed JUnit5. I just replaced `@RunWith()` with `@DataJpaTest` and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` is a compeletely different beast :) Its not even a unit test anymore, it runs Spring infrastructure with real repositories, so make sure you understand the difference. For plain Unit test powered by JUnit 5, use `@ExtendsWIth(MockitoExtension.class)`

Comment: Oh, Thank you! I will definitely have to read more about that! Thank you so much. For now, this is doing my job! You can make the official answer do I can close the thread if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the spring boot is tagged here, the chances that you're using spring boot 2.x (1.x is outdated these days)

But if so, you should be running JUnit 5 tests (spring boot 2.x works with Junit 5)

So instead of `@RunWith` annotation, use `@ExtendsWith`

Then place the breakpoint in the test and make sure that mockito extension has actually worked and the mock is created.

Now as for the `given` - I can't say for sure, I haven't used this syntax (BDD Mockito), but in a "clean mockito" it should be `Mockito.when(..).thenReturn`

All-in-all try this code:

```java
@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AppointmentServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Test
    void shouldGetAllAppointments() {
        List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
        appointments.add(new Appointment());

        Mockito.when(appointmentRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(appointments);

        List<Appointment> expectedAppointments = appointmentService.getAllAppointments();

        assertEquals(expectedAppointments, appointments);
        verify(appointmentRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```